# My map doesn't update after I add a new item through the putifAbsent method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

My map doesnt take any new values that I add to it. 
This is my Provider:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../classes/transaction.dart';




class Transactions with ChangeNotifier {

  Map<String, Transaction> _userTransactions = {

   'ju': Transaction(amount: 45, date: DateTime.now(), title: 'socks', accountType: 'timr', notes: 'joa' , icon: Icon(Icons.today,), id: 'kololdcd', repeat: 'always')
  } ;
  
   
 Map<String, Transaction> get userTransactions {
   print (_userTransactions);
   return {..._userTransactions};
   
 }
 


   void addNewTransaction({String txTitle, double txAmount, DateTime chosenDate,
      String txAccountType, String txNotes, String txRepeat, Icon txIcon, String txId}) {
     
    
    if (txRepeat != 'Einmalig' && _userTransactions.containsKey(txId)){
    _userTransactions.update(txId, (existingItem) =>  Transaction(
      title: existingItem.title,
      amount: existingItem.amount,
      date: DateTime.now(),
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      accountType: existingItem.accountType,
      notes: existingItem.notes,
      repeat: existingItem.repeat,
      icon: existingItem.icon,
    ) );
    
    } else {
      _userTransactions.putIfAbsent(txId, ()=>  Transaction(
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: chosenDate,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      accountType: txAccountType,
      notes: txNotes,
      repeat: txRepeat,
      icon: txIcon,
    ));

    }
    //final cant be changed anymore
    print (_userTransactions);
    notifyListeners();
    
  }
  
  
 


}
```

This is my listener:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/transactions.dart';

import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final transactionsData = Provider.of<Transactions>(context);
   final transactions = transactionsData.userTransactions;
   print (transactions);
 
    return transactionsData.userTransactions.isEmpty
        ? LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constraints) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Keine Transaktionen hinzugefügt. ',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.6,
                
                ),
              ],
            );
          })
        : 
       
                 
                                     ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: transactions.length,     
                 itemBuilder:(context, i) {
                    String key = transactions.keys.elementAt(i);
                   return Card(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 8,
        horizontal: 5,
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          radius: 30,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Text('\$${transactions[key].amount}'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          transactions[key].title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
           DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transactions[key].date),
        ),
      
      ),

    );}
                  );
  }
}
```

I am calling this provider method from an other screen:

```js
void _submitData() {
    
    if (_amountController.text.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);
    final enteredAccount = _accountController.text;
    final enteredNotes = _notesController.text;
    final enteredRepeat = _repeatController.text;
    final enteredIcon = Icon(MyIcon.paying);
    var uuid = Uuid(options: {});

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty ||
        enteredAmount <= 0 ||
        _selectedDate == null ||
        enteredAccount.isEmpty ||
        enteredRepeat.isEmpty) {
      return; 
    } else {
      Transactions().addNewTransaction(
        txTitle: enteredTitle,
        txAmount: enteredAmount,
        chosenDate: _selectedDate,
        txAccountType: enteredAccount,
        txNotes: enteredNotes,
        txRepeat: enteredRepeat,
        txIcon: enteredIcon,
        txId: uuid.v1(options: {
          'node': [0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab],
          'clockSeq': 0x1234,
          'mSecs': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
          'nSecs': 5678
        }),
      );
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
   
  }
```

If I add a new pair to the map, it is shown in the addTransactionMethod (print Statement gives me the values of the new item). But as you can see in the print statement of the userTransactions my map _userTransactions doesnt take the new value, it only keeps the predifened one that I hardcoded.

This is the Debugger Konsole (the first print Statement is from the addTransaction Methode - the second one is directly from the userTransaction map:

I/flutter ( 5636): {ju: { kololdcd,socks,2020-02-14 22:33:09.616563, timr,joa,always,Icon(IconData(U+0E8DF)),45.0}, ho: { 2020-02-14 22:33:09.621559,Why not,2019-02-11 00:00:00.000, jes,cool,always,Icon(IconData(U+0E80D)),78.0}}

I/flutter ( 5636): {ju: { kololdcd,socks,2020-02-14 22:32:14.896756, timr,joa,always,Icon(IconData(U+0E8DF)),45.0}}

As you can see the Second item is missing in the second print.

[As you can see in the picture the new value sin't added to the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0TSd.png)

How can I solve the issue? I just want to add items to this _userTransactions.

Would love to hear some suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your class widget is a `StatelessWidget`. You can't update a `StatelessWidget` because being able to update it would mean it has a state that can be updated. For your approach, you will have to change your widget to being stateful:

```dart
class TransactionList extends StatefulWidget {
  TransactionList({Key key}) : super(key);

  @override
  State get createState => _TransactionListState();
}

class _TransactionListState extends State<TransactionList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

An alternative solution which would allow you to leave your widget as a `StatelessWidget` (which is more recommended anyway) is that instead of calling `Provider.of` directly, you use a [`Consumer`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) to automatically pull the provider data to a builder method. The `Consumer` will also handle the rebuilding of your widget in the event that your transactions object gets updated.

```dart
class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Transactions>(
      builder: (context, transactionsData, _) {
        ...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't work. The issue is not the listener. The map doesnt update in the provider file, which is strange.

Comment: You Can See it in the second print Statement that it id doesnt update.

Comment: My _userTransaction map doesn't update in the Provider class. Do you know if there is something wrong in the provider class? The listener should be all right because I added the consumer widget, and it runs the build method, but the map isnt updatet there, because it wasnt updatet in the provider map. The issue should be the provider.

Comment: @georg  You haven't shown the code where you create the Provider or call `addNewTransactions`, so at this point any suggestion I could make would be a blind guess. On a side note though, why are you calling `putIfAbsent`? Why not use `_userTransactions[txId] = ...`?

Comment: Thank you for your contribuition. I solved the issue. I added a listener to the class where i am calling the addTransaction method from. I thought I only need listeners where I need the providers information and didn't think about providers function. Thank you that you asked me where I am calling the method from.